# Use of please, in a statement related to a request

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Is the following sentence correct, with regard to the use of the verb 'please'?

> I ask you to please confirm the reception of this message.

Comment: This is correct, and I think it would be more natural with "please confirm ***your receipt*** of this message."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all "please" is here an adverb, not a verb It is sence 1 of entry 2 in [The Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/please)

The sentence

> I ask you to please confirm the reception of this message.

is not incorrect, but a bit old-fashioned or unusual in form. In this context "receipt" is much more often used then "reception", and "I ask you" is usually omitted as superfluous, leaving

> Please confirm receipt of this message.

or often just

> Please confirm receipt.

The inclusion of "I ask you" **could** imply frustration, perhaps at previous failures to confirm, as another answer suggests. Or it might be simply a slightly excessive formality.

In other contexts, where the request is more serious and less routine, the form

> I ask you to please  X

might seem more natural, but still a bit formal.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with the sentence is that it seems rather impatient and aggressive, as if they've failed to confirm receipt of all your previous messages, despite you asking nicely - the sort of thing that it rather hard to explain or learn, I'm afraid. I'd write "Would you confirm receipt of this message, please" or just "Please confirm receipt of this message." I'm not sure it's a general rule, but moving "please" to the beginning or end of the sentence feels somehow less impatient.

Comment: I think it is the omission of "I ask you" thet decreases the intensity of the request

Answer (score -2):

Overall, the question is not correct, but with regards to the word please, it is.

A better way to form the sentence would be

> May I ask you to please confirm the reception of this message?

Comment: What's incorrect about it? Also, it's not a question, it's a request.

Comment: I ask you is not a proper way to say it.